# How to compare read byte from file to single character string

Tags: java

I have a text file where I need to check if there is a `"1"` or a `"0"` at a certain position. Note that it's the string representation of the numbers I'm checking. I've tried this:

```
RandomAccessFile dictionaryFile = new RandomAccessFile("path");
if("1".equals(new String(dictionaryFile.read()))){
    // do stuff
}
```

but it results in:

```
ir/PersistentHashedIndex.java:322: error: no suitable constructor found for String(int)
        while("1".equals(new String(dictionaryFile.read()))){
                         ^
constructor String.String(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to String)
constructor String.String(char[]) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to char[])
constructor String.String(byte[]) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to byte[])
constructor String.String(StringBuffer) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to StringBuffer)
constructor String.String(StringBuilder) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to StringBuilder)
```

Seems to me like `String` needs a byte array instead of just a byte to initialise a string. But I only want to give it one number. How can I achieve this? Can I maybe convert `"1"` to its byte representation?

EDIT: Sorry about the comparison mistake, guys, I sorted it out. Same problem persists.

Comment: That's not the way to compare Strings even if that did work.

Comment: Please read [how to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: what is `dictionaryFile.read()` ??

Comment: In such cases you should consult the official API (its free, really!) `InputStreamReader.read()` returns an `int` (containing the current bytes value), not a `byte` as you expect but there is no constructor accepting an `int` parameter in `String`...

Answer (score 1):

> no suitable constructor found for String(int)

It means you are passing integer value to **[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** constructor whereas, there isn't any constructor for `String`, which accepts `int` value. If `dictionaryFile.read()` return `int`. Then, you could do

```
if (dictionaryFile.read() == 1)
{
```

**==Edited==**

If you are forced to compare as String, then you just add empty string to it.

```
String temp = dictionaryFile.read()+"";

if ("1".equals(temp))
{
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to compare it to integer 1. I want to compare it to "1". Is there really no way to just make a string out of a single byte??

Comment: @Sahand any specific reason ? and what is `dictionaryFile.read()` ? what does it return ?

Comment: Because I have my own file format where "1" means the current position is occupied and "0" means not occupied.
dictionaryFile.read() is a RandomAccessFile method, I've added the object declaration in the code.

Comment: It seems like your solution results in "49" instead of "1" if a string "1" (49 in int value) is read from file.

Comment: @Sahand FYI.. my solution only convert int to String, which you asked. It doesn't change the value.